# Trying to forward calls to mobile using Node.js and Twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio

I have a Twilio voice number setup (trial at this stage) and I have a node.js server running using ngrok.

I am trying to forward an incoming call to a mobile number on the webhook end point using this code:

```
const ivrTwilRes = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
ivrTwilRes.dial({callerId:'+xxxxxxxx'},
function(){
    this.number('+xxxxxxxx');
}).record();

o_Res.set('Content-Type','text/xml');
o_Res.send(ivrTwilRes.toString());
```

but it keeps coming back with an application error or simply hangs up.

I can get it to work correctly using Twilio Studio but I want to eventually have the forward to number generated dynamically by my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone that is looking for the answer.

```
app.get('/voice', (request,response) => {

    const twilio = new VoiceResponse();
    twilio.dial('+xxxxxxxxxx');

    response.set('Content-Type','text/xml');
    response.send(twilio.toString());
});
```